# How to duplicate a collection with unlinked children using Python

Tags: scripting, collections

I am very new to Blender and I'm trying to attempt a somewhat trivial task of duplicating a collection that I have selected **without** linking any of the children within the collection, so far I'm working with the current code that works well enough to duplicate the collection - however this only unlinks the parents and the children remain linked which is cumbersome to change given many iterations, I'm not sure how to amend this to satisfy my requirements.

```
iter = 0

while iter<2:
 for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen

    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
            override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
            bpy.ops.outliner.collection_duplicate(override)
            break
 iter = iter + 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: it's not trivial to duplicate a collection without its children. What you could do instead is duplicate the collection, then unlink everyone of their children. When you say children, are you talking about children collections or children objects ?

Comment: @Gorgious I see - I have children objects within the collection describing the hierarchy pythonically would be something like the following: {Collection:{Object1:[Object2,Object3]}} if that makes sense. As you suggest I would like to unlink all of the children within the resulting duplicate. Simply put I am trying to duplicate the object and change only the colour of the new object without it influencing the original collection.